# Rename directory from within directory?

Tags: shell, directory, rename, cd-command

How would I rename a directory from within that directory?

For example:

```
~/tmp $ rn tmp2
~/tmp2 $
```

I can do that with: cd .. && mv tmp tmp2 && cd tmp2, but not sure how to make it into one command.

Comment: out of curiousity: why does it have to be one command?

Comment: For example, if I'm in a git rep, and want to change it's name, I can: 1. cd'ing out of it, change the name, cd into it. 2. use a one liner. It's out of sheer laziness.

Comment: cd ..; mv foo bar; cd bar is a one liner. but i'll buy into the sheer laziness :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to your .bashrc.zshrc file would allow you to replicate the behaviour I described:

```
#in .{bash,zsh}rc file
rn () {
  local D="${PWD##*/}"
  cd .. && mv -- "$D" "$1" && cd -- "$1"
}

#in terminal
~/tmp $ rn tmp2
~/tmp2 $
```

[1] `${PWD##*/}` taken from [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371261/get-current-directory-name-without-full-path-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

`mv ../dir ../dir2`

but then you might get errors like directory not found or ls not working f you don't reenter the directory with the new name.

in "one command":

```
mv ../dir ../dir2 && cd ../dir2
```

Comment: I want to stay in the directory, that is be moved into the new directory.

Comment: you can still work, but pwd command will not show the correct path, for that you need to reenter the directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mv /tmp /tmp2
```

but to move in `tmp2` , you'll have to do

```
$cd ..

$cd tmp2
```